# Adding PostgreSQL support to already installed PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have php-5.3.6 and postgresql installed in my Fedora 13. But it seems that postgresql support is not enabled in php. My phpinfo() page doesn't show any PostgreSQL section, neither pdo_pgsql section.

I checked /etc/php.ini, and it shows that PostgresSQL is enabled.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/php.ini | grep ^pgsql
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
```

Is there any way I can add postgresql support to php without recompiling it from the source? Is there any other files I need to make some changes?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Run `yum install php-pgsql php-pdo_pgsql` to install the PHP Postgres package.

Comment: Great! You may want to run `yum list "php*"` to view all the php packages that are optional extras.

Comment: Nice! Works perfectly! 
Thanks

Comment: apt-get install php5-pgsql for ubuntu users

Comment: you can use `sudo yum install php-pdo_pgsql`

Answer (score 3):

Here's what solved the issue for me (on Windows, using WAMPSERVER):

- Uncomment `extension=php_pgsql.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` in php.ini
- Restart all services in WAMPSERVER
- Make sure that php_pgsql and php_pdo_pgsql are checked in the WAMPSERVER menu -> PHP -> PHP extensions
- In httpd.conf add the line `LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/libpq.dll"` before the line `LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll"`
- Restart all services again and check that the WAMPSERVER icon becomes green.

Source:
http://toolkt.com/site/install-postgresql-and-phppgadmin-in-windows-with-wamp/

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem earlier on today on Windows. I couldn't access "Phppgadmin". Whenever I tried to access it I get this error: "Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option". So I did some search which got me here.

Anyway, I was able find a way around the problem using the instruction I found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) as follows:

1. Browsed to the php.ini file found in C:\xampp\php\php.ini and opened it in text editor as an administrator
2. Uncommented the following by removing the semicolons prefexing; `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`, `extension=php_pgsql.dll` and `extension=php_pgsql.dll`
3. Saved the file and restarted Apache

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem I got earlier on Windows. I couldn't able to access "Phppgadmin". Whenever I access phppgadmin getting error: "Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option".

Finally, got the solution.

You need to follow this path C:\xampp\php\php.ini and opened it in text editor as an administrator and remove the semicolons pre-fexing; extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext", extension=php_pgsql.dll and extension=php_pgsql.dll Saved the file and restarted Apache

Answer (score 0):

uncomment `extension=pgsql` in **php.ini** file (for window xampp installation )